# Branch.io initSession's callback is not called on first session in iOS sometimes

Tags: ios, branch.io

After downloading app from AppStore (as well as when using xCode in some cases) registered callback in AppDelegate (**Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions:...)**) is not called at all (or is called after 40-50 seconds, which is not acceptable). Opening the app using Branch when it is already installed causes no issues (callback is called, data is correct, everything is fine). Same API in Android works as expected. I'm positive that [documentation](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration) is followed step by step. Example of BranchUniversalObject data:

- canonicalIdentifier: user/{user_id}
- canonicalUrl: https://{domain_name}/u/{user_id}
- $ios_deeplink_path/$android_deeplink_path: open/u/{user_id}

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: part of code in AppDelegate that is responsible for handling Branch data.

```
Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, isReferrable: isReferrable) { [weak self] (params, error) in
    if let data = params as? [String: AnyObject], let value = data["+clicked_branch_link"] as? Bool {
        self?.clickedBranchLink = value
    }
    registerDeepLinkHandler?(params, error)
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your AppDelegate codes?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code doesn't invoke setIdentity before initSession.
As per Branch integration docs -

> If it is invoked before, then we will silently initialize the SDK before the callback has been set in order to carry out this method's required task

[image]